# Some OpenSSL source that mysteriously doesn't work

Tags: c++, ssl, tcp

This has me crawling up the walls. I can't find out why this source doesn't open a socket.  It's simple enough but doesn't work. Can someone please help me with this? Thanks for your consideration! BTW: I get no text on the screen and it blocks with the BIO_do_accept() function.

```
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/x509v3.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <process.h>
using namespace std;

int main()  {

    SSL_load_error_strings();
    SSL_library_init();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    BIO *abio, *cbio, *cbio2;
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    abio = BIO_new_accept("4444");

    /* First call to BIO_accept() sets up accept BIO */
    if(BIO_do_accept(abio) <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting up accept\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(0);
    }

    /* Wait for incoming connection */
    if(BIO_do_accept(abio) <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error accepting connection\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(0);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Connection 1 established\n");
    /* Retrieve BIO for connection */
    cbio = BIO_pop(abio);
    BIO_puts(cbio, "Connection 1: Sending out Data on initial connection\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "Sent out data on connection 1\n");
}
```

Comment: you really have to call BIO_do_accept() two times?

Comment: yes I don't know why but yes I do

Comment: so, it blocks in BIO_do_accept()... where's the client code which connects to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this (on cygwin, with gcc 4.5.3 and openssl-devel 1.0.1 installed)

Your **[code posted in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=3144880#3144880)** compiled with

```
g++ -std=c++0x ./test.cpp -lssl -lcrypto  -o test
```

The resulting code *obviously* doesn't work, because the code refers to `server.crt` and `server.key`:

```
openssl genrsa -out server.key 1024
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
```

Creates a selfsigned certificate with unprotected key (you'd use `genrsa -des3` to add a passphrase to the key).

Now, I could test it properly:

```
test& # in the background
openssl s_client -connect localhost:12120
```

This lands you in a kind of SSL-enabled `telnet` client and it worked nicely.