# boost asio ssl simple encryption program

Tags: c++, ssl, encryption, boost-asio

I am quite new to secure networking and I am trying to make a simple networking program with `boost asio ssl` and I have read all of the documentation available and also lots of questions and answers, but no one has yet asked:

**Can I make a simple encrypted network using `boost asio ssl` without all of the certificate and verifying stuff.** Just a public/private key pair on both ends, then some sort of public key exchange (handshake?) and then secure communication?

If I am wrong or mistaken about something, please do correct me. Simple examples would be much appreciated.

Comment: why? [just make your own certificate](http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html)

Comment: @Theolodis That is one idea that might solve my problem, but I am interested whether there is an implementation for what I am trying to do, because I already have the keys generated earlier in the code and I would like to not change my earlier code, because I need to start generating certificates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here for a minimal demo client/server using Boost Asio:

- [Boost Asio SSL Certification on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968931/boost-asio-ssl-certification-on-ios/21970561#21970561)

This answer adds instructions on how to create a certificate and use it:

- [Some OpenSSL source that mysteriously doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973988/some-openssl-source-that-mysteriously-doesnt-work/9993280#9993280)